# Differentiate session for different tab in php

Tags: php, session

I am developing a site in php.
It uses session to store customers details & details of filters & product which he has selected.
But when I open the site in next tab, the same session values are reflected over there.
I wont that only customer details should get shared for next tab & not the selection of product and filters which he has done on first tab.
So how can I achieve the same to differentiate values of filter/product & customer information for another tab in php.

Comment: It is not possible to differentiate between two tabs using PHP. The server will view both tabs as the same connection and thus, they will share SESSION variables

Answer (score 0):

It is quite complex for a developer as well as end user aspects. Because when you see any real world web applications we see that site is fully dependent on browser. Sessions are stored with browser dependent. You need to develop or manage self handler to store each tab data and pass each tab individually.